# How to add node/add page into my view?

Tags: views, users

I am trying to build my own content administration page and I want to use default drupal `node/add` page (that one with list of content types available to user) inside view. So far I have made view header with PHP:

```
<?php 
    module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
    $node_page = node_add_page();
    print render($node_page);
?>
```

but it just displays info that I don't have any content types created (I have of course).

*core of the poodle:* **code acts like user doesnt have permissions to create any content at all**

Any idea how to solve this, or where is the problem?

Comment: never a dumb question. "build my own content administration page" - Specify further what you are trying to achieve. And maybe there is a different way to achieve that

Comment: just a page with content created by users (already have it) and links to add new content. Reason why i want to use this drupal function is, that page node/add shows only links to add content that user has permission to create. I can add direct links such as "node/add/article", but those could be seen by users without rights to create them.

Comment: Breaking this down further "but those could be seen by users without rights to create them" - drupal takes care of permissions at the core level, thus if your users have drupal level permissions then they wont ever be overrided. You can also set user permissions at admin/people/permissions . Thus you can set content type level permissions here, Look under Node at this page.

Comment: i know. Problem is that code in my post acts like user doesnt have permissions to create any content at all (even when im user 1). And on the other side, direct links to content creation form (node/add/article) will be visible to anyone (content creation page itself wont be, but its not nice to provide link to "access denied" page).

Comment: Yes, attacking the core problem would be nice because that may resolve a lot of this for you, Can you verify permissions to see the authenticated user, administrators have the related permissions to create content. Not having any permissions to create content looks weird. Enable devel and check values on that page to see whats blocking it. Also if you can add a screenshot of what happens when you try to create content?

Comment: well, i created new testing view with without any complex queries and with that php code to get something relevant with devel and guess what: Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in .../modules/system/system.module on line 2129 - i guess that is the problem (`node_add_page()` calls `system_admin_menu_block()` and that line is part of it). its weird this error doesnt show up in preview and that other view - php code is the same.